# Change format of Date?

Tags: c#

I'm currently getting the date from a standard month calendar and displaying it in the dd-mm-yyyy format. What I would like to do is make it so that when the date is grabbed along with the display it will also store the date in the format yyyy-mm-dd without the hyphens being present so for example today would be 20160511 and I was wondering how I could do this?

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean. If you have a `DateTime` value, you can format that however you want, e.g. `string text = date.ToString("yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`. Is that all you're looking for?

Comment: Would you send us your code please?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using `DateTime`? Then you could do:

```
date.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

Comment: The best way to do it

Answer (score 0):

string date = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd");